# What happens when we issue read command from disk?

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, kernel, dma

Suppose there is a process which issues a read command for particular sectors to kernel.

1. Now kernel issues this read command to disk and that process which requested those particular sectors sleeps ( get blocked ) and is it in the waiting queue.
2. Now kernel issues this command to disk ( This is my understanding ) Read these sectors and after reading those sectors into your buffer , copy those bytes/data into this location ( and issues this command to DMA Controller )
3. Now disk controller after reading those bytes/data into the buffer, with the help of DMA ( it asks DMA controller ) transfer those data to the memory region specified by the kernel.
4. Now in the meanwhile ( the bus was busy ), so CPU was busy doing some calculations which does not needs the bus ( doubt ).
   Now after data transfer from the disk is complete , disk issues a interrupt to the CPU.
5. CPU acknowledges the interrupt and invokes the interrupt service routine and this ISR is responsible for waking the concerned Process which had been submitted into the queue.
6. Now as i have read through some of the answers on stackoverflow , i comes to my knowledge that ISR knows which process to wake up exactly , which is confusing to me as at this moment , we dont know which process we need to wake up and even we don't know which request just got served via disk I/O.

My questions are :

- How does processor/ISR finds out which process to wake up
- When does the DMA controller comes into action ( is it processor asks DMA controller to take the action for transferring bytes from disk to memory or is it disk controller which is responsible for asking DMA controller for its service )
- How does DMA fields such as source address register and destination address registers gets filled ???

Comment: In between the disk controller and the host CPU (and DMA controller) would be an interface, e.g. SATA.  DMA would occur between the SATA host controller (not the disk controller) and main memory.  The CPU is in full control of the DMA controller, and responsible for setting up each DMA operation.  Same is true for the SATA and disk controllers.